# Cannot change permissions for dtrace on MacOS

Tags: macos, sudo, chmod, ptrace, dtrace

I was looking at [this article](https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/12/02/osx-strace-equivalent-dtruss-seeing-inside-applications-what-they-do-and-why-they-hang/).

It recommends allow the usage of dtrace without root for current user, so I run:

```
$ sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/dtrace
Password: # I enter in my password
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/sbin/dtrace: Operation not permitted
```

Does anyone know if I should, and how I should, allow dtrace to run without root permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what article you were reading, but its advice is unsafe and incorrect. You should never change permissions on files stored in system locations, like `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`. (Indeed, [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) makes this impossible.)

If you need to use dtrace, run it using `sudo`.

Comment: yes after reading the comments in that article, I think yer right

Comment: I forgot to add the link to the original OP, now it's on the OP, so OP is now updated lol

Comment: https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/12/02/osx-strace-equivalent-dtruss-seeing-inside-applications-what-they-do-and-why-they-hang/